# How do I fix Azure pipeline error NETSDK1152?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-pipelines, blazor

While running my pipeline, it fails at the publish phase with 2 errors.

```
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1


##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : ...
```

The pipeline also lists all paths to files with duplicate names, even if the contents are different. The pipeline worked fine before with the duplicate names, but now throws and error and will not proceed. what is the correct fix for this?

Comment: You'll need to give us more details to give any meaningful answer. Most probably there's more error messages or warnings...

Comment: It may also be that you're now using .NET 6, since that shipped yesterday. Do you have an explicit "Use Dotnet" task to set the SDK version in your pipline?

Also, see: https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/1868/Publish-error-Found-multiple-publish-output-files-with-the-same-relative-path

Comment: I don't have a Dotnet task, and the application is a blazor app with UI and API both on 3.1. There are no other errors, and this is the only warning I am seeing 
##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I got the same problem after  updating from .NET 5 -> .NET 6. I have both `UseDotNet` and `DotNetCoreCLI` `restore` build tasks in the pipeline but in `DotNetCoreCLI` `publish` I get the NETSDK1152 error because of libman.json file in both blazor client and blazor server projects. Marking them as Do Not Copy to output directory does nothing to change the error.

Answer (score 21):

I think my pipeline is using Dotnet6 even though the app is only 3.1, and this was added to fix it. I don't know if this is the correct fix, but it is working.

I added this to the csproj files that have duplicate file names.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is where I found it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#erroronduplicatepublishoutputfiles

Answer (score 1):

This is a breaking change introduced in .NET 6
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/duplicate-files-in-output

You have multiple ways of fixing this:

1. Evaluate your resources in the project where "CopyToOutputFolder" is set to "Always" and remove if they are unnecessary. How MSBuild handles this is, it tries to copy these resources to output folder after the build is completed.
2. Target a specific SDK during the build by adding it in global.json
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection
   You probably have "rollForward" option set to "latestFeature" that automatically uses the latest SDK, so you can remove that and target .NET 5 or earlier.